# Matplotlib error while making kivy executable for windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy, pyinstaller

I am making kivy executable for windows. My app contains matplotlib graph. The python file runs fine. But after creating executable, when I try to run exe file it gives me following error -

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "myfile.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg

File "\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

File "site-packages\kivy\garden\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     '''

File "\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

File "site-packages\kivy\garden\matplotlib\backend_kivy.py", line 244, in <module>

File "\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
     exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

File "site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 121, in <module>
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
[13504] Failed to execute script myfile
```